# Exception in Tkinter callback - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

I am stuck with this error while fetching a record from postgresql table by id (int). I would appreciate if you help me sort this out please.

---

**THE ERROR**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\VENV Project\studentdataentryapp.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    button = Button(frame,text="Search By ID", command=lambda:search(id_search.get()))
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\VENV Project\studentdataentryapp.py", line 27, in search
    cur.execute(query,(id))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

---

**HERE'S THE CODE**

THE CODE

```py
def search(id):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres", password="maryam")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = '''select * from student where id=%s;'''
    cur.execute(query,(id))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print(row)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

id_search = Entry(frame)
id_search.grid(row=13, column=2, sticky=W)

button = Button(frame,text="Search By ID", command=lambda:search(id_search.get()))
button.grid(row=14,column=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument to `execute()` should be a `tuple` or `list`, so:

`cur.execute(query,(id))` should be `cur.execute(query,(id,))`.